# Hibernate Criteria API versus JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria, jpql

Which of the two methods are faster especially for over 1 million rows in database?
And what is best practice, to use JPQL or Criteria?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice is to log the SQL statements created by Hibernate and analyse their execution plans for both methods. It's really hard saying which approach would produce more optimized SQL.

Comment: Indeed. Something like log4jdbc can help a lot there.

Comment: The people have spoken.

Comment: Well I did not expect this comment :))

Answer (score 1):

Criteria is a more clean way to do it, the output is the same, but as best practive I recommend Criteria.

[Criteria Example](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-criteria-examples/)